# "No thread-bound request found: " error while initializing spring beans at application startup when using session scoped spring beans

Tags: apache-flex, spring, session

I am working on a flex based web application and want to set some properties at session scope and hence using scope="session" attribute in a spring bean. Following are my configurations:-

### Spring bean:-

```
<bean id="cacheLoader"  class="com.....CacheLoader" scope="session">
<property name="commonService" ref="commonService" />     
<aop:scoped-proxy></aop:scoped-proxy>
</bean>
```

### web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Still  i am getting this error:-

*Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.cacheLoader': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.*

Please suggest me if i am missing on some configuration steps or doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some singleton (default) scoped bean referring to "cacheLoader" in your context configuration. Spring by default instantiates singleton beans during startup and no http session is available during that time hence your exception.

I would recommend factoring out session-specific part of the cacheLoader and make sure no singleton references it.

Comment: My understanding was using "<aop:scoped-proxy></aop:scoped-proxy>" will make initialization of singleton beans successful. Have i misunderstood something?

Comment: @user1166967 Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. It should work as long as you don't try to perform a call to session-scoped bean in your singleton's init method. You need to check for that and work around this.

Comment: Love you man ! You solved my problem too where i call a request scoped bean to execute in the init of my singleton bean